# Where clause that is passed as parameter to a method not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I'm able to pass the where as a lambda expression into a method as one of the parameters.

**Method** -

```
public Collection<SelectionItemByGUID> GetLookupsByCashBookId<T>(Func<T, object> cashbookID) where T : class        
    {
        var items = new Collection<SelectionItemByGUID>();
        var itemsT = All<T>(null)
                .Where(cashbookID);
        items = new Collection<SelectionItemByGUID>(CopyListObjectProperties<SelectionItemByGUID>(itemsT.ToList()));
        return items;
    }
```

But it does not allow me to have the where clause and returns an error. This is the error below,

**Error Message** -

'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a defination for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Where(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, System.Func)' has some invalid arguments

It does not return any error messages when I call the method,

**Calling the method** -

```
GetLookupsByCashBookId<Employee>(x => x.CashbookId == cashBookId);
```

Am I passing the where clause incorrectly into the method?
It there a conversation that must be done inside the method?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your Func definition is wrong, it should be:

```
Func<T, bool>
```

You must return bool from your Func.And you can't use `All` like this, because it returns bool result:

```
All<T>(null).Where(cashbookID);
```

First get your `Employee` items collection from somewhere (maybe from your db context) then you can use `Where` extension method.